# Configure CKEditor - WYSIWYG HTML editor

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

What is the way to configure CKEditor - WYSIWYG HTML editor for Drupal 7 sites?

Answer (score 1):

You can install the CKEditor module for Drupal for that: http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor

You will have to include CKEditor by yourself, which you can download from [here](http://ckeditor.com)

Install the Drupal module and put the ckeditor folder from the second link under sites/all/libraries and that should be it.

Comment: After installing module, need to add paths to CKE Editor settings where the editor should be enabled.

Comment: okay its cool.. i have installed it .. now my question is how to add this in a "Content Type" ?

Comment: If it's installed correctly, CKEditor should appear every "Long text with summary" type field when adding a new content.

Comment: i can see the editor in Content Type settings page .. but not in the Content creating form ..... also , i cant found libraries in my host server of this path> /sites/all/libraries , so what to do